# Why does fflush() takes variable amount of time flushing the same piece of data

Tags: c++, file, fflush

I have a file descriptor to which I always write two floats. Note that I always call rewind() before writing anything to the file, which means that I am always writing to the first line. Basically, think of it as maintaining "current state" inside a file. I also call fflush() after writing to it. I was facing latency spikes in my application and when I checked, I found that fflush() is taking generally around 2-3 microseconds (yes, I have a wicked fast server) but at other times (after about 6-7 "normal write-flush cycles") I see the time taken is spiking up thousands of times (15000+ microseconds)

Can you tell me what I must check in this scenario? How do I fix/debug this issue?

Comment: Well, you're writing to storage of some kind, possibly (you haven't said) an HDD. The two local persistent storage mechanisms I can think of (HDDs and SSDs) will both have varying response times based on what else they have to do. 150000 *micro*seconds is still a *really short period of time*.

Comment: Would using a memory mapped file help?

Comment: @Wildling *Would using a memory mapped file help?* Read [this post](http://marc.info/?l=linux-kernel&m=95496636207616&w=2) from Linux Torvalds.  `mmap()` is **NOT** some magic that makes everything faster.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what else is happening to the drive. The first bottleneck would be when your data is queued to be written so it would depend on what else the OS (or other data source) is doing to the drive.
Related, there might be a delay getting exclusive control over the data bus.
If it's a magnetic drive and not an SSD then there's also the time it takes for the physical write head to move to the correct track and sector to perform the write. Note that because this is a physical action, it takes much longer.

In short, unless you are deep, deep within the OS then there's no guarantee about exactly when a requested low-level action takes place.

Answer (score 1):

`fflush()` doesn't flush the write buffer *to the disk*. It flushes the write buffer to the operating system. The operating system may, and probably does, use a buffer of it's own. Copying bytes from one buffer to another is very fast (compared to disk). Occasionally, when the buffer is full or for another reason, the OS may flush it's own buffer to the disk. When the data is *actually* written to the disk, your program must wait much, much longer.

This is very abstract view of what's going on. In reality, a real OS probably won't return from `fflush()` until the data is written to the [journal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journaling_file_system).

Comment: So what are my options here? Will using a memory mapped file would help?

Comment: @Wildling Buy a faster disk, ssd preferably. Don't call `fflush`, or if you do, use an asynchronous thread, so that the latency doesn't matter.